# SQLPlus is there a flexible datatype with no static amount of letters

Tags: sql, oracle, types

if I use varchar2 as a string datatype I have to set the amount of letters. If this would be varchar2(100) it seems that I have the problem that SQLPlus fills a value with less letters with blanks till it reaches 100. This problem pops up with the spool command, then it prints 100 letters to the Output file even if some values of the column have less letters. This also shows up when I execute a query on the console. So my question is, is there a datatype where I dont have to set a static amount of letters? Normal SQL knows the datatype Text where you dont have to set this. Is there a similar datatype in SQLPlus?

Thats the code I'm using to create the output

```
SET PAGESIZE 50000
SET LINESIZE 540
SET FEEDBACK OFF
set echo off
set mark csv off
set sqlformat csv
set trimspool off
set heading on
set headsep on
set wrap off
SET COLSEP "|"



SET TERMOUT OFF
spool C:/Data/DHBW/PA1/Oracle/outputTable.log
select * from konten where rownum<=10 order by Konto;
spool off;
```

Thats the output
[image]
In the column "Firma" it prints a big blank space cause some rows later there`s a values which is much longer.

Thats the query to create the table:

```
SET TERMOUT OFF
create table konten(Konto number,Anrede varchar(5), Vorname varchar(20), Nachname varchar(30), Stadt varchar(38), Bundesland varchar(38),Firma varchar(120), TelNr varchar(30), Institut varchar(55), Eroeffnung varchar(15), IBAN varchar(12), Anfangssaldo varchar(18), Kontostand varchar(18));
desc konten;
trimspool on;
exit
```

And thats the control file I'm using to import the data to the table "konten":

```
load data
infile 'C:/Data/DHBW/PA1/JavaCSV/kontenMiddle.csv'
into table konten
fields terminated by ';'
(Konto, Anrede, Vorname, Nachname, Stadt, Bundesland, Firma, TelNr, Institut, Eroeffnung, IBAN, Anfangssaldo, Kontostand)
```

These are the first 10 rows of the CSV which is imported:

```
Index;Anrede;Vorname;Nachname;Stadt;Bundesland;Firma;Tel.-Nr.;Institut;Eroeffnung;IBAN;Anfangssaldo;Kontostand
1;  Frau;Herzlinde; Busch ; Meerbusch;Nordrhein-Westfalen;   Firma MAT ;    ;   VR-Bank;    22.11.1980; DE56126376; 6508.6; 957268.04   
2;  Frau;Leonille;  Schwab ;    Schwaebisch Gmuend;Baden-Wuerttemberg;   Baeckerei Raedlein ;   04323/26513493; DZ Privatbank;  21.12.1973; DE42747841; 1883.24;    263757.76   
3;  Frau;Snejana;   Baumann ;   Koblenz;Rheinland-Pfalz;     Metzgerei Kalinowicz ; 030/76672589;   VR-Bank;    13.08.2006; DE91771527; 7238.34;    775892.57   
4;  Herr;Klemens;   Zimmermann ;    Tuebingen, Universitaetsstadt;Baden-Wuerttemberg;    Gewerbegebiet Weiherweg ;  06731/42974286; Sparda-Bank;    03.06.2012; DE81371787; 3365.81;    355406.19   
5;  Herr;Eilef; Haase ; Luenen;Nordrhein-Westfalen;  Apotheke am Kreuz ;    ;   Sparda-Bank;    17.02.1990; DE12562130; 6403.39;    579210.5    
6;  Frau;Hadburg;   Loeffler ;  Bocholt;Nordrhein-Westfalen;     Kuechen und Baeder Zeyco ; 06592/5582092;  DZ Privatbank;  21.07.1978; DE73874811; 6113.86;    503603.39   
7;  Frau;Avsin; Gaertner ;  Darmstadt;Hessen;    DB Agentur&Reisebuero Hartwig Seger ;  07143/46168911; DZ Privatbank;  13.05.1986; DE33659772; 9584.49;    202764.71   
8;  k.A.;Richard;   Winter ;    Fuerth;Bayern;   Kraft ;    ;   VR-Bank;    05.11.2020; DE86352502; 8101.75;    861537.14
```

The first line is not getting imported, because the headers are already given with the creation of the table.

Comment: `SQL*Plus` does not "fill a value with less letters with blanks".  It would if you declared a fixed length data type like `char(100)` but not if you declared a variable length data type.  You can declare a data type as `clob` if you want to have no limit on the length of the data stored in that data type (well, there is a limit that depends on the Oracle version but it's several TB at least).  SQL*Plus won't display the entire contents of a `clob` unless you change the `long` setting.

Comment: My guess is that you are really asking about `SQL*Plus` formatting commands rather than data types.  My guess is that you really want to `set sqlformat csv` or add a `/*+ csv */` comment to your query to generate a CSV file https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/05/formatting-query-results-to-csv-in-oracle-sql-developer/ or to set the `trimspool` setting to `off`.

Comment: Ok thanks so far. I've tried the trimspool in front of the spool command to write the data to the txt-File, but it still prints the blank spaces to the text-file. And ```set sqlformat csv``` didn't change it either. Do you have another idea?

Comment: It would help if you edited your question to show a reproducible test case (DDL to create the table, DML to insert the data, the `SQL*Plus` script you're using, the file you're creating, etc.).  Otherwise, we're trying to guess at what you're seeing and what the actual problem is.

Comment: Sorry, makes sence. I've edited the question

Comment: It would be great if you provided the DDL to create the table and the DML to insert the data so we can reproduce the issue ourselves.  In my comment, I should have said to set `trimspool` to `on` rather than `off`.

Comment: Now I added the queries for the insert

Comment: That's getting close to a reproducible test case.  But we don't have the data file you're using to load the data (a subset of the file is preferable as long as it reproduces the problem you're having).  Or the DML to insert the 10 rows of data.  If you want someone to manually type out the DML to insert 10 rows of data by looking at the image you posted, that eliminates a lot of people that could potentially help you.

Comment: I've just added the first 10 rows of the CSV file, you can copy them.

Comment: What exactly are you complaining about? The fact that FIRMA is padded with spaces  to a fixed size? If so, that is a feature not a bug.  You say in your question that *"it prints a big blank space cause some rows later there`s a values which is much longer."* Column headings and spacing is always fitted to the largest returned value. What do you want to happen instead?

Comment: I'm looking for a way that each line of the output is shown in the shortest version, because for me it's not that important that heading and spacing is fitted. Because the problem is that a import CSV with 2 million rows is 350mb large and if I'm outputting this one the file it gets 1gb large, this might be because of the blank spaces.